# ORACLE PL/SQL Multiple objects insert using a single insert Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Let's say that I have something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_A AS OBJECT (
  var_n            number,       
  var_v            varchar2(12),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_A(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_A) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_A AS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_A(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_A) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.var_n    := NULL; 
        SELF.var    := NULL;
    RETURN;
    END;
END;



    FOR RECORD IN cursor_x
    LOOP
    
    --> Some logic
    --result is t_A object
    insert_t_A(var_t_A);
    END LOOP;
    commit;
```

Is is possible to store all created t_A objects somehow and insert it after the loop at once ? In a single insert statement ? Insted of single inserts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, here's how to do it (though your type body had an error, and in my example, it's not needed, as I don't use the constructor at all, so it can be removed from the type):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_A AS OBJECT (
  var_n            number,       
  var_v            varchar2(12),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_A(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_A) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_A AS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_A(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_A) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.var_n    := NULL; 
        SELF.var_v    := NULL;
    RETURN;
    END;
END;
/

create table t_a_table (ocol t_a);

declare
type t_aob  is table of t_a index by binary_integer;
tob t_aob;
i   pls_integer:=1;
begin
    for p in (select rownum rn from dual connect by level<11) loop
        tob(i):=t_a(p.rn, p.rn||' str');
        i:=i+1;
    end loop;
    
    forall i in 1..tob.count 
        insert into t_a_table values (tob(i));
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly.  What is the meaning of  type t_aob  is table of t_a index by binary_integer ? What does it do ?

Comment: The declaration of "var .... is table of ... index by ... " creates a collection type as an [Associative Array](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005). In this particular creating a collection of object types t_A.